# Is it good to duplicate the opencart module?

Tags: module, admin, opencart

Well I want to make a custom page in `opencart` admin panel to insert and delete some data from opencart database

**For example :**

Set an image slider on opencart home page and fetching images from database & for insertion of images, I want to create a custom page in opencart admin panel ??

So how can it be possible ??

Comment: Yep, duplicating of the already existing module, renaming and modifying the necessary lines is the way you can learn how the stuff is done and to save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate any module and create other for your needs. Remember to duplicate and change the filename so the "new" extension can work properly.

**Folder to consider for admin:**

```
admin->controller->{type of module}->module's name
admin->model->(type of module)->module's name
admin->language->english (always)->(type of module)->module's name
```

**optional:**

```
admin->language->(other languages)->(type of module)->module's name
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try,

1,Login as Admin-> systems -> design ->banners -> insert ->
YOUR BANNER NAME-> add banner ->

Title: YOUR TITLE

Image: YOUR IMAGE -> Save

2, Login as Admin-> extensions -> Modules ->Slideshow -> Edit -> add Module -> SELECT YOUR BANNER -> Save

Answer (score 1):

Also when duplicating modules be aware that you may also need to change the existing class name to different one. For example when duplicating module flat rate you will also need to change in the controller /admin/controller/shipping/flat.php :

```
class ControllerShippingFlat extends Controller {
```

to something new like :

```
class ControllerShippingFlatDuplicate extends Controller {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's posible, but in my opinion if you want to create a new "admin page" in your Opencart you can do it using vqmod.

so, you don't have to rewrite any core file.

you can donwload any free extension on the opencart website to take an example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply duplicate some simple modules available in opencart admin panel like Welcome module or Banner or Slideshow module.

This method will help you to disable the module or change the position of content in future.

Duplicating opencart module tutorial : http://opencart.hostjars.com/blog/58

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner it's better to duplicate an existing module and modifying it as per requirement. When you get the idea of how opencart modules work, you can build modules from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is pretty safe and sound to duplicate a module in opencart and it is a bit logical with any of the cms as no one is going to create a module from scratch for a very little functionality like inserting some values to database.

As depicts you just want to insert some images links, so you can proceed with replicating the catalog / information functionality in opencart admin panel.

You just need to create a new table in database to store new modules data and fetching new module data in front end.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to duplicate and create a method just to change and save the same information in existing tables, then you should only create a controller and a visual output for this, otherwise you will already have the data.
Just duplicate (controler/..., view/..., languague/...) referring to the module and desired action, name it something similar something like ex: banner -> banner_plus